# I keep getting "NA" in my output using the glmmTMB package in R

Tags: r

I am new to programming in R and I am needing to use a zero inflated mixed effects generalized linear model for my data. I have found online that using the package glmmTMB is best for this. I have code and it runs, but I am missing some of my output- it says "NA". What can I fix so it gives me values instead of "NA"? I also keep getting a warning that says "Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix" and do not understand what that means, any help?

I have looked up the error code online on a troubleshooting page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html), but the explanation was way over my head.

Here is what my code looks like (there are variables commented out so they we can just look at the specific ones for now):

```
No.WavesModel2 <- glmmTMB(No.WavesScaled~(MudTemp+I(MudTemp^2)+
                                      #Ba+I(Ba^2)+
                                      #Cd+I(Cd^2)+
                                      Pb+I(Pb^2)+
                                      #Sr+I(Sr^2)+
                                      #Zn+I(Zn^2)+
                                      #Fe+I(Fe^2)+
                                      Mn+I(Mn^2)+
                                      #Cu+I(Cu^2)+
                                      CarIndex+I(CarIndex^2)+
                                      No.Pedestrians)+I(No.Pedestrians^2)
                            (1|Site),
                          data=MaleWavingR,
                          ziformula=~1,
                          family=poisson)
summary(No.WavesModel2)
```

These are the warning messages that show up in my output:

```
1: In nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control = control$optCtrl) :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
2: In nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control = control$optCtrl) :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
3: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
```